# iterate object key value as an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand to iterate an array like object:

```
var obj = {0:'a',1:'b'}
function logArgs(){
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments,function(elem,idx){
console.log(idx + '. ' + elem);
})
}

//now calling this fails:
logArgs(obj)

//logs
0. [object object]
```

But I wanted a result like this:

```
0. a
1. b
```

Comment: But you just passed one argument. Your function iterates over `arguments`; why would you expect more than one thing to be logged?

Comment: it's loggin [object object] but I wanted to be 0. a

Comment: Well I know what you *wanted* it to be, but the point is that your code iterates over the **argument** list, not over the **contents** of each argument. But that's why I asked the question, so thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over the keys of each object parameter passed to your function, you'd want something like this:

```
function logArgs(){
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments,function(elem,idx){
    console.log("argument " + idx);
    Object.keys(elem).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log("  key " + key + ": " + elem[key]);
    });
  })
}
```

With your sample object, that'd log

```
argument 0
  key 0: a
  key 1: b
```

Note that the order of iteration through object property names, either with `for ... in` or with `Object.keys()`, is not defined in JavaScript. A runtime environment is free to hand over the keys in a literally random order any time you ask for them. They don't, of course, but writing code to depend on that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't an *array-like* object because it misses one key feature.  A `length` property.

To iterate over an object, you can use this code:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  // Protect against inherited properties.
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
  }
}
```

In ES5, you can do:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(
  function(key) {
    var val = obj[key];
    console.log([key, val]);
  }
);
```

**Important notes**

- NEITHER of this is guaranteed to return the values in array order.  It may return `[1, 0]`.
- As @jfriend00 mentioned, the property names are *strings*.  (This is also true of arrays, but arrays tend to hide that fact from you.)

Comment: Your second option will generate output like `0, 0` and `1, 1`.  You have to go back to the actual object to get the value of the property.

Comment: @jfriend00 Arg, yes.  I was focused on getting the syntax right I didn't check the output.  Thanks.  Fixing now.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in a different way using `Object.keys()`

Please refer the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqk33ske/)

```
var obj = {0:'a',1:'b'}
var keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key + '. ' + obj[key]);
});
```

Using the same logic in OP's function.

```
var obj = {0:'a',1:'b'}
function logArgs(obj){
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);

    keys.forEach(function(key){
        console.log(key + '. ' + obj[key]);
    });

}

logArgs(obj)
```

Logs:

```
0. a
1. b
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual iteration of properties of an object is like this:

```
var obj = {'0':'a', '1':'b'};

for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // property name is in prop
        // value is in obj[prop]
        console.log(prop + ": " + obj[prop]);
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/45jwx6zg/

Keep in mind that (per the spec of the language) the properties of an object are not in any guaranteed order and all property names are string values.

---

You can't directly iterate an object (even one with 0, 1, 2 ... n as properties) like an array because it doesn't have a `.length` property.  You could (although I don't know why this would be useful), extract the properties of the object into an array using `Object.keys()` and then use that for your iteration, but I'm unclear why any of that would be useful and not just much more complicated code than is required.

```
var obj = {'0':'a', '1':'b'};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) {
    console.log(prop + ": " + obj[prop]);
});
```

Unless you wanted to provide a custom sort to the keys, I can't see any reason to do it this way.  `Object.keys()` also requires IE9 or higher.